# I'm trying to make an array and sort it with a sentinel value which is 0 but it's not working it's giving me an error

Tags: assembly, mips

I want to prompt the user for input then i want to take that input and put it into an array. Then i want to print out the array. I know I can just print them out without putting them in an array but this is just for my practice.

```
 .data
    array:  .space 40
    prompt: .asciiz "Enter an integer (0 to quit) :"
    text:   .asciiz "After sorting, the list of integers is:"
       .text
       .globl main
    main:

        la $a1, array
        read_numbers:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, prompt
        syscall

        li $v0, 5
        syscall

        sw $v0, 0($a1)
        addiu $a1, $a1, 4

        beqz $v0, sort
        j read_numbers

    sort:
        la $a1, $array

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, text
        syscall

    loop:

        lw $t0, 0($a1)
        addiu $a1, $a1, 4

        beqz $t0, done

        li $v0, 1
        move $a0, $t0
        syscall

        j loop

    done:
```

The error i'm having is: Instruction references undefined symbol at 0x00400050 [0x00400050] 0x3c010000 lui $1, 0 [$array]      ;24: la $a1, $array

Comment: Please format the code properly and add an explanation into the question. Especially explain what "not working" means and what error you get

Comment: `$` is only used with registers, not with labels. `la $a1, $array` should of course be `la $a1, array` just as you managed to do it a few lines earlier. I VTC as a typo.

Comment: I fixed it and it's still giving me the same error

Comment: Step through it the debugger.